# Fully Connected Layers for segmentation with corner points

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am working on a segmentation problem, for simplicity I am using rectangular masks. At the beginning I am using the vectorized images as an input data and corner points of the rectangle [x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max] as a vector as an output.

I am trying to use fully connected NN with 10 hidden layers (I also changed results seems same)  but it does not converge! I see that the loss function decreases from 3000 to 160 but stops there.

From those who are experienced, I will appreciate your kind comments!

Thanks

Comment: Im looking for an explanation for this! I checked everything. I also can share the codes if required

Comment: I found some explanation for this: When the network is too shallow or too complex, I does not work, almost same results are coming out: No convergence! So I changed the design of network and make it simple, it converged.
In the case of dim reduction, it heavily depends on the application: may cause cleaning important data (like my case)